# Cannot Play Audio in a SCORM Package from Moodle in Safari

Tags: ipad, safari, html5-audio, moodle, scorm1.2

We are using Moodle 2.5.4 to launch a SCORM 1.2 package on the iPad 4th gen in Mobile Safari and a Mac to launch it in Safari 7.0.1 and 7.0.6. There is both a video file and an audio file playing at the same time in the course, but on the iPad only the video plays when we launch the course in Moodle. Upon inspection it appears the audio file is being played with an HTML5 audio tag.

We have verified that both the client's old LMS system and SCORM cloud are capable of running this content. We did not alter anything to do with SCORM module launches and the same course runs all audio and video just fine in other browsers.

Is there any way in which we could get this content to play in Moodle the same as it does everywhere else?

Comment: After further testing is seems that the issue goes away if we disable Moodle's settings to require https. The audio appears to play fine when launched through SCORM Cloud over https. The problem is that we need to require https, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Safari and Mobile Safari don't like playing audio over HTTPS when the server is using a self-signed certificate. Upon testing in an environment with a valid SSL certificate everything worked fine. So in the end this was not a Moodle issue at all.